# Media Library not listing any media items when browsed from Image Field of an item in content editor in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library, sitecore7.1

Media Library not listing any media items when browsed from Image Field of an item in content editor.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an item from Content Tree
2. Browse for an image from Image field.
3. Media Library UI displayed without previously uploaded images.

Expected : Media Library should display all media items available.

Note:

1. Inconsistency observed on multiple attempts(occasionally loads with a delay of 20 seconds - Is there any solution/fix to reduce this delay?)
2. Network is not an issue
3. User is having all the necessary roles and permissions.
4. Issue observed in all the browsers.

Version: Sitecore.NET 7.1 (rev. 130926)

Any help would be appreciated in knowing the root cause for  Media Library not listing the media items.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below attached screenshot - [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your indexes have been built. The Sitecore 7.1 image UI uses the search API to display content, so if the indexes haven't been updated/build properly it will not show any data.

You can rebuild your indexes by logging into the desktop, click the Sitecore button in the bottom left, go to Control Panel and select Indexing. Click the Index Manager and follow the wizard to rebuild.

Comment: This is what UI error reads as ""statusCode":403,"error":{"message":"Access to site is not granted.","type":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException","stackTrace":"   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Request.CheckSecurity.Process(RequestArgs arguments"

Comment: Is that when you log into the desktop or the control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a data source in the media field? That version of Sitecore has a known bug where such sources doesn't work. If so, ask Sitecore support for the workaround patch for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore.Speak.ItemWebApi set allowanonymousaccess to true for the site name="shell"
This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have to enable the Sitecore.Speak.ContentSearch.Solr.config if using SOLR.